# Javascript does not execute Object methods

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build some objects to make my life a bit easier, but somehow I can't get it working. I got the following code:

```
function Paragraph(className, innerHTML, parentId) {
    this.className = className;
    this.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

Paragraph.generateParagraph = function() {  
    console.debug(this.parentId); // Expect 'testDiv'
    alert(this.parentId);   // Expect 'testDiv'
};

function initialize() {
    var paragraph = new Paragraph('testClass', 'testTitle', 'testDiv');
    paragraph.generateParagraph;
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

When I try to execute this code nothing happens. I expect the console.debug and alert in the *generateParagraph* method to be executed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add methods to the constructor's prototype, not the constructor itself.

```
function Paragraph(className, innerHTML, parentId) {
    this.className = className;
    this.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

Paragraph.prototype.generateParagraph = function() {  
    console.debug(this.parentId);  // Expect 'testDiv'
    alert(this.parentId);   // Expect 'testDiv'
};

function initialize() {
    var paragraph = new Paragraph('testClass', 'testTitle', 'testDiv');
    paragraph.generateParagraph();
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

Comment: -1, I can't see how this is any different to the code posted in the question.  In any case, it's not the correct answer.

Comment: @J-P: it wasn't, when I downvoted and left my comment.  It was edited within the 5 minute editing window to add the parenthesis to `paragraph.generateParagraph()`.  The irony is that those edits don't leave an audit trail so I'm unable to remove my downvote until the answer is "properly" edited

Comment: @Andy, edit it yourself (by adding some white-space or something...) and then you'll be able to reverse the downvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

change

```
Paragraph.generateParagraph = function() {
```

to

```
Paragraph.prototype.generateParagraph = function() {
```

You added the function as a property of the constructor function, rather than to the prototype. By adding the function to the prototype it will be part of the object created when calling the constructor function using the new keyword.

Also, you need parentheses to the call to generateParagraph, otherwise you get a reference to the function, rather than calling the function:

```
paragraph.generateParagraph();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the generateParagraph function, as parenthesis are missing...

```
paragraph.generateParagraph
```

This gets the function as a callback...
To call it:

```
paragraph.generateParagraph();
```

Comment: still wont work, method needs to be added to ctor prototype, not ctor.

Answer (score 1):

you're not invoking the function.

```
paragraph.generateParagraph();
```